# Undocumented tumblr theme variables, what do they do?

Tags: tumblr

[Tumblr Optica Theme](https://www.tumblr.com/theme/37310) uses many Variables that are not listed on [Tumblr Custom Themes Doc](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes). Such as:

```
{URLEncodedTweetSummary}
{URLEncodedShareString}
{URLEncodedMailSummary}
```

etc.

What are the functions of these? And why aren't they documented?

Comment: Since I'm not Tumblr dev, it's impossible for me to say for certain what all undocumented blocks exist, but we've known for a while that several exist. Also, URLEncoded is documented, so that's really not what you should be asking, I suppose? The undocumented blocks/tags that I know of are: `{MobileAppHeaders}` `{block:Hidden}` `{Name}` `{TweetSummary}` `{ShareString}` `{MailSummary}` and I know the function of each because, intuitively, they do what their name happens to be, which you can learn from comparing live blog code to the mark-up. I have no idea why they aren't documented.

Comment: Just to throw another one in the mix: `{TagsAsClasses}` isn't documented completely either, as it fails to mention using tags for styling purposes only.

Comment: @Ally If you fancy sticking up an answer, I am happy to add to it. If not I will make a wiki answer.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about `URLEncoded`. `{block:Hidden}` is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876219/what-is-the-blockhidden-and-when-is-it-used), it really doesn't exist & so doesn't render anything inside it. `{Name}` is documented now as I can see. About the rest, I noticed, kind of, what they do but don't have a clear idea. Tumblr really should document them. Thanks. @Ally

Comment: Check out Chloe’s list of all the undocumented variables she could find [here](http://bychloethemes.tumblr.com/undocs) or [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171018223231/http://bychloethemes.tumblr.com/undocs)